# How to get Current datetime of client side in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I am trying to access current datetime from Mysql using now() functions which shows date time from the server side which is residing at different timezone and set to GMT. So say If I am in India I have to add 5:30 Hrs. to calculate exact time. But don't know if someone access application from other timezone. Then How to handle?

Is there any way in Mysql to get current date time from the client side. Otherwise I have to rely on Application to send current date every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get client's time.
What you may do, is get the server's time from the sql on the client's code.
After that you can add/sub hours according the client's timezone.

The reason you need to server's time is to have logs and other stuff without depending on client's time in his computer. you may even want in the future to have logs from more than one computer for a single client.